# Command completion does not complete the files in the current directory

Tags: bash, autocomplete, command

Something is wrong with my tab completion.

Let's say I do this:

```
cd test // works fine, go into test directory
ls // works fine, displays all of the files
```

Let's assume I have the following files:

```
abc.txt
ada.txt
afg.txt
```

If I type `a` and then `TAB` for auto complete, it displays something different like:

```
a2p
a2x
... // bunch more
```

I feel like it thinks I'm in a different directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are commands. If you start typing on the commandline and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it won't expand the subdirectories and files of your location but available commands.

Basically, tab completion is context sensitive. If you just start writing and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will complete commands found in your `$PATH`. If you have already written a command, `cd` for example, it will complete the files and directories in your current location. For some commands, it will also complete available options to that command.

Comment: Note that the "double tab" while entering a path may match the OP behavior expectation: it will list all the files available in the currently displayed directory.

Comment: @LaurentC. only if you have set `./` to be in your `$PATH` and even then, only the executable files.

Answer (score 5):

Bash completion does not work as you expect. I will try to give a rough explanation.

When you are typing a command (or if you haven't written anything yet) and press the tab key, bash try to complete with any of the available commands on your `$PATH` (`a2p` and `a2x` are just two commands). Once you have written your command, if you press the tab key again it will try to complete with the arguments for that command (the directory `test` in your example is an argument to `cd`).

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the previous answers, anyone looking to solve this issue, this tutorial shows how you can go about creating custom completions:

https://iridakos.com/programming/2018/03/01/bash-programmable-completion-tutorial

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/418219)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).